# Getting compilation error when try to run workflow with Anchors in UiPath Studio:

Tags: input, compiler-errors, uipath-studio

Getting compilation error when try to run workflow with Anchors in UiPath Studio:             Input Dialog - First Name: Expression Activity type 'VisualBasicValue`1' requires compilation in order to run.  Please ensure that the workflow has been compiled.                        UiPath Studio version: 2023.4.4

HOW TO RESOLVE THIS ERROR. I AM LEARNING RPA AND NEW TO THIS. PLEASE HELP.

Here is the practice exercise I am doing:                                                        Build a workflow that fills the form on ‘www.rpachallenge.com’ website with the input data
received from the user.  - - - -
Ask the user to provide their:
o First Name
o Last Name
o Address
o Company Name
o Role in Company
o Email
o Phone Number
Submit the user’s data in the ‘www.rpachallenge.com’ form
Display a message box confirming the submission of the data
Use anchor-based selectors for this exercise

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? This seems like something is wrong with your UiPath installation, and I would recommend 1. Restarting your machine; 2. Uninstalling and reinstalling UiPath, making sure to follow the recommended and default installation settings.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I reinstalled UiPath and now I don't see the issue... thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when trying to use a variable in my Object Repository element descriptor (error occurs while debugging didn't try published).

To fix this I removed the Computer Vision option in the Descriptor which I believe is causing an issue.
My best guess is that the error is thrown because computer vision with a variable requires compilation (process performed when publishing) debugging the project runs it through an interpreter not a complier.